# How to Visualize JSON data present in google datastore using Data-Studio Tool?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I was exploring the Data-Studio tool of google cloud which helps in data visualization, but I think that this tool can only be used for SQL data visualization. How can I visualize JSON data present in my datastore using Data-Studio?

Is there any other tool present which can integrate my google datastore and help me visualize this JSON data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no [direct connector to Datastore](https://support.google.com/datastudio/topic/7332343), but you can use this more or less convoluted path for visualizing this data: Datastore -> Storage -> BigQuery -> Datastudio

Let me break this down step by step:

1. **Export the entities**:

   First we need to use the [export utility](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/export) from Datastore to extract the data from Datastore. This will generate a file in Google Cloud Storage.
2. **Import into BigQuery**

   Then we can [import the export file into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#cloud_datastore_export_service), or use it directly as an external data source.
3. **Connect to Datastudio**

   Once we can access the data through BigQuery, it can be added as a [source in Dtastudio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296).

With a little bit of trickery and ingenuity, you can [schedule Datastore exports periodically](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export) to the same file, and have that file as an [external datasource in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage), meaning that you can visualize the data updated with the periodicity configured in the scheduling of the exports, and you have to do nothing manually.